# Just moved into my new flat. One of my 2 laptops connected to the wifi automatically, and Googling was no use

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, connection

I just moved into a new condo, and my main working laptop automatically connected to my router that I let a network/cable company install a few weeks ago.

I was baffled by this.

I cannot find any useful results on Google - everything points to tutorials to turn off automatic connecting for a wifi network in particular, but that's not precisely my question. Even if it was, I do not trust that just ticking some box on this PC for a wifi connection will prevent other devices in the future from doing the same.
I did find some advanced forum threads about ''roaming sensitivity'' but it seems like a risky thing to mess around with the context of my question.

**Instead,** my question is (sorry if I am repetitive here), why the heck did this computer **automatically connect** to a password-protected network?
The computer also stated (hovering over the network icon in the task bar) that the network was **Public**, it's not supposed to be this way, I changed a setting and now it says it's ''Protected'' instead.

The bottom-line is,
Please tell me how this was able to happen, and,
I do not want people to be able to connect to my network without a password
(which is what I just did, with my own laptop that is).

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: I let a network/cable company install ........   I would be inclined to ask the network company.

Comment: Yes sir, I may have to check with them about the public/private connection thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @kansha, your issue might happen to others, so there's a valid reason for editing the question again, and moving the IMPORTANT EDIT to an answer. Answering your own question is acceptable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tried to do what you suggested, did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IMPORTANT EDIT!!!*

I just realized that this may have happened, because I use 2 laptops with the same Microsoft account, and the other laptop was (I think) manually connected to this network on the day of installation, weeks ago.
I only realize this because some time ago, I did something like changing the system language, or the way time is displayed (AM/PM vs 24hs) on 1 laptop and the other laptop automatically followed suit, which I was first surprised by, and then manually switched it back for the other laptop.
However, this still begs the question: why did this computer tell me the wifi network was **public?**
*I am terribly sorry if it's against the rules that I just made my own thread mosly redundant.*

I also noticed my Android phone hasn't connected automatically.
I've been learning to program lately and I guess learning problem solving skills came in handy today haha...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).